# What's the difference between and Event Processor and a Microservice

Tags: architecture, microservices

In Event Driven Design, there is the concept of the **Event Processor** which is the node within the event chain that applies business logic to/from an event message. Usually a single responsibility.

in Microservice Design, the **microservice** is the smallest, standalone unit within an architecture that applies business logic to input.

These are just different words for the same thing no? Am I missing something here. Is there a difference or is this just people doing things because they don't want to be the same as those other people doing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Event Processor is a technical component. A service or a microservice is a  unit of the functionality provided by the system, don't take it too literally, but you could call it a business function to distinguish it from the technical components.

Comment: If I understand you, an event processor is essentially a component of the system, and the service is a functionality offered to the user (man or machine). If I understood that correctly, I still don't understand how they differ once you put them on paper. It seems like a meta distinction rather than an implementation distinction.

Comment: @F.Lamingo The microservice can also be made by more technical components. An interface and an implementation class together can make a microservice.

Comment: So the technical difference then would be that an Event Processor has no interface to the outside world while a microservice does.

Comment: After some more reading based on your answer. I think I understand it better. So an event processor is a strictly technical component (logic provided by the underlying systems/technologies) that have no business logic within the code whereas a service could be a mix of business components and technical components. I marked your answer correct, but if you could let me know if I'm on the right track here I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @F.Lamingo Answer to the above post is no. You are making confusion over the proper type of abstraction.

Comment: Then please unconfuse me. Can you give me clearly different examples of each?